# Login PHP keeps returning invalid username or password even if the fields are correct?

Tags: php, mysqli

So basically, when I press login on my form, even if my username and password are correct in the input fields, I keep getting the invalid username or password error. I am unsure how to fix this, as everything looks correct in my code. How would I fix this so I can log in? Here is the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$dbname     = "users";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $username = (string)$_POST["username"];
        $password = (string)$_POST["password"];
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'");
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if ($username == $row['$username'] && $password == $row['password'])
            {
                $regKey = $row['regKey'];
                $_SESSION["reg"] = $regKey;
                die("YOU DID IT");
            }
            else
            {
                $mysqli->close();
                die("Error, invalid username or password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking your time to help.

Comment: Do you have one record with that username? try to print in while this variables $row['$username'], $row['password'] and tell me what is the output; comment the if and else in the while

Comment: Sql injection warning. You are using mysqli too which is great, just take the last step and bind your queries. Also, are you hashing the password? Please do yourself and your users a favor and hash the passwords.

Comment: My username on your website, @AbsoluteZero, will be `'; DROP DATABASE; -- `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as HawasKaPujaari say you were trying to fetch an invalid column.

But also, I think you can have some problems with your session, you need to initialize, like this:

```
@session_start();
```

> Just before this:

```
$_SESSION["reg"] = $regKey;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I was just having issues with that.

Comment: @AbsoluteZero You're welcome! Please accept my answer if it worked! =P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
if ($username == $row['$username'] && $password == $row['password'])
```

try this:

```
if ($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password'])
```

You were *most probably* trying to fetch an invalid column `$row['$username']` from the database.

Answer (score 0):

What is the need of if(condition inside while loop).? Check your condition in sql query only.

```
.
.
.
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$result = mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$CountResult=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($CountResult==1)
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
      $regKey = $row['regKey'];
      $_SESSION["reg"] = $regKey;
      die("YOU DID IT");
  }
}
else
{
   $mysqli->close();
   die("Error, invalid username or password");
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Sql injection is very normal nowadays. And why do you need to fetch data if count result is 1 and username and password is matching.???